# HK hermitian if H and K commute

Tags: matrices

$\text{Let H and K be hermitian operators in unitary space.}$
$\text{HK is hermitian only if HK 
commutes (HK = KH).}$

How would one prove this statement without the use of eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $H$, $K$ and $HK$ are hermitian, then $HK = (HK)^\dagger = K^\dagger H^\dagger = KH$.